# dependence among sub-questions in the essay exam

Tags: hypothesis-testing, validity, scoring-rules

In the essay question, one main question includes several sub-questions that are ordered based on the thinking skills, from low (knowledge level) to high (analysis level).

Main question (total: 10 points)
Sub-question 1 (knowledge) 
Sub-question 2 (comprehension) 
Sub-question 3 (analysis)

Situation 1: Since each sub-question is built upon the previous one, when answering subq1 wrongly, it is likely that the student will also answer subq2 wrongly. 
Situation 2:It is also likely that the student answers subq1 and 2 correctly, but answers the subq3 wrongly.

What is the best way to make a marking scheme for both situations?

Comment: I'm not sure that the situations are really all that different. The sub-questions are ordered in difficulty, so if you get Q1 wrong you're unlikely to get Q2 correct, and if you get Q1 correct then you're (a little) more likely to get Q2 correct. I would just say give a person a point for each question they get correct, but the fact you're asking makes me think you have a reason for believing this would potentially be inappropriate. Am I right?

Comment: My focus in more on the second situation. If the learning goal is that students should reach the analysis level, then should we assign points to the underlying lower levels?

Comment: Imagine I have three students: student A is below average, B is average, C is above average. Student A gets Q1 correct, but Q2 and Q3 wrong, so I give them 1 out of 3. Student B gets Q1 correct and Q2, but Q3 wrong, so I give them 2 out of 3. Student C gets Q1, Q2, and Q3 correct, so I give them 3 out of 3. The below average student gets a lower score than the average student, who gets a lower score than the above average student.  Such a scale makes reasonable sense, no?

Comment: I'd recommend you read any introductory text on IRT, and most introductory psychometric texts written in at least the past 45 years. This idea of tests consisting of questions with varying difficulty is extremely common, and this approach of summing the number of correct answers is typical.

Comment: I still have another question: don't you think it is reasonable to assign more points to the more difficult subq3 than subq1 and 2?

Comment: Can IRT also be applied in essay questions???

Comment: Not really, because the assumption would be that a person who got subQ3 correct would also have got the previous two right, so they get full marks. As long as you assume that all of the questions are assessing the one general dimension, then only counting the number of questions a person got correct is a valid way to go

Comment: There is certainly a literature on essay grading and IRT. I don't know it well enough to know if it would be appropriate in your case though.

Comment: The reason why the questions are structured based on the complexity is to spot at which thinking level students can achieve. There are two common practices in course assessments. One is to assign points to each of the sub-questions and the other is to assign points only when the subq3 is answered correctly.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you suggest is to simply count  how many subquestions are answered correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would do. As I understand the second practice you'd be losing potentially valuable information: If you only get points for getting subQ3 correct then you can't differentiate between subQ1 level people and subQ2.